# Use of setOnClickListener()

Tags: android

I am very new to Android app development, so will ask a very basic question. What is the work of `setOnClickListener()`?

In the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sudoku);

    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}`
```

What is the function of `aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this)`?

Answer (score 3):

[`setOnClickListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) indicates that the supplied `OnClickListener` should be called with `onClick()` when the view is clicked.

In this case, the `OnClickListener` is the `Activity` itself. `OnClickListener` is an interface which this `Activity` implements.